Should or should I not use the article in this sentence? Does it matter either way?
"What kind of a test are you preparing for them?"
"What kind of test are you preparing for them?"
What is the difference between these sentences meaning-wise? Is there any? Grammarly suggests omitting the "a" is the way to go, but I can't tell why. Is it because it's common in American English to omit the "a" in such cases?

The version with the indefinite article is colloquial. Many people say it, but in writing that strives for a more polished or formal style it isn't used.

@PaulTanenbaum That question is more concerned with grammaticality. I'm sure the sentences I've used are grammatically correct, I just want to know if removing the article makes a difference meaning-wise. I'd also like to know if the omission of "a" here is something American English speakers are more likely to do.

More likely to omit than not, or more likely than Brits to omit?

@PaulTanenbaum If it can be both, then both. If not, the former.

@FumbleFingers Checking that question in a bit.

Grammarly is no doubt repeating the advice that has been given to students for most of the 20th century in English classes: "kind of a" is "talky" and the indefinite article should not be used for that (stylistic) reason. "kind of a" is a well-attested construction in American English.


'a test' means some type of a single test which is performed in the relevant field. (countable noun)


'test' means any type of test which is in the conceptual framework. (uncountable noun)


What kind of a test are you preparing for them?

This implies the asker has pre-information of the existence of a test and 'for them' also means the asker has some kind of knowledge of why the listener is preparing a test.

What kind of test are you preparing for them?

The asker has less information about test and presumes that it is reasonable to have some test(s). But it's not certain what kind of test and how many kinds of tests will be done.

The questioner's advance knowledge of some type of test is expressed in both sentences with are you preparing for them.  The questioner has the same knowledge in both.    The teacher could say "I plan to give the students a test" and either of those sentences could follow and they would have the same meaning.  The form with a test is the more likely of the two  in a conversational rejoinder because the repetition of the indefinite article is a tag of sorts.

Thx for your providing good insights. As a learner, a slightly nuanced diffrence , even 'a/an' could be a meaningful one sometimes though it's not much likely in this case especially for a conversational and colloquial situations. I've learned that 'a/an' is possible for countable nouns when they are in a single entity. 'A dog is a faithful animal.' In this case 'a dog' means the whole species of dogs. If so, I guess 'test' wit no any article could mean the conceptual(abstract) one.
